# GroupBy by a condition and create different anonymous model per group EF6

Tags: c#, .net, group-by, entity-framework-6, sql-server-2016

I am using EF6 + SQL Server.

I want to make a query to one of my tables and to map the result by a condition into 2 groups.

In each group the results should be fetched as a different kind of model. The idea here is that there are lots of fields I need in 1 case but not in the other one, and I, of course, prefer to get all the data in 1 trip to the database.

I am trying to do something like:

```
IEnumerable<long> idsWithFullModel = new[] { 1, 2 };
  
var groups = context.MyTable
   .GroupBy(
      x => idsWithFullModel.Contains(x.id),
      x => idsWithFullModel.Contains(x.id) ? 
       new 
       {
          field1 = x.field1,
          feild2 = x.feild2,
       } : 
       new 
       {
          field1 = x.field1,
       });
```

When I am trying to do it, I get an error

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'IEqualityComparer because it is not a delegate type' compiler error

Is it possible to run this kind of query?

I was trying to use objects as @kamaz08 suggested:

```
    IEnumerable<long> idsWithFullModel = new[] { 1l, 2l };
  
var groups = new List<(long id,int field1,int feild2 )>{(1l, 1,2), (3l,1,2)}
   .GroupBy(
      x => idsWithFullModel.Contains(x.id),
      x => idsWithFullModel.Contains(x.id) 
      ? (object) new 
       {
          field1 = x.field1,
          feild2 = x.feild2,
       } 
       : (object) new 
       {
          field1 = x.field1,
       } 
   
      );
```

But now I receive the next error:

> Unable to cast the type 'Anonymous type' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

Comment: Since I don't know that much about EF and Linq - it would be interesting to see an example of what your data looks like, and your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You can still map to object.

```
    IEnumerable<long> idsWithFullModel = new[] { 1l, 2l };
      
    var groups = new List<(long id,int field1,int feild2 )>{(1l, 1,2), (3l,1,2)}
       .GroupBy(
          x => idsWithFullModel.Contains(x.id),
          x => idsWithFullModel.Contains(x.id) 
          ? (object) new 
           {
              field1 = x.field1,
              feild2 = x.feild2,
           } 
           : (object) new 
           {
              field1 = x.field1,
           } 
       
          );
```